# Unable to show Base64 image in Popover, Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

The situation is that, I want to open an image in bootstrap popover v2.3.1
And the image is in Base64 format. 
On the click of the button [id='imagePopoverButton'], the popover window is opening but the base 64 image is not appearing.

I am sharing the below code snippet, if some one can help me in trouble shooting the same.

```
<!-- js func, which load Base 64 img format via Ajax -->

function showImagePopover() {
            $.ajax({
                url : getContextPath()
                        + "/app/Application/showImagePopover",
                type : 'POST',
                async : false,
                success : function(jqXHR) {
// In this scope, i have fetched the ajax image, but i am not been able 
//to show that up in popover
                }
            });
        }
/***************************************************************/
<!-- Popover function js, html:true -->

$("#imagePopoverButton").popover({
        content : showImagePopover(),
        html : true,
        trigger : 'click',
        placement : 'right',

    });

/***************************************************************/

<!-- via Clicking of the button, ajax call is suppose to load base64 image in popover -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" id="imagePopoverButton"      rel="popover">imagePopover</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following below the comments

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "data:image/png;base64," + jqXHR;
image.id = "image_id";
image.width = '500';
image.height = '500';
$('#imagePopoverButton').html(image);
```